# Failed to display view when calling function (Nativescript)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angular, typescript

I'm developing a mobile app and i'm trying to display a list of items on the view. The list of items will only display after some event happens on the view such as clicking a button or typing a letter in the search bar, until then there's nothing. The function gets called from XML using onload="loaded". I will show in the code below. Any ideas on how to get the view to display on load and not wait for something to happen? First i will show the XML and then the typescript.

```
 <ListView [row]="row" [items]="bdUserBundles" (loaded)="load()" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout class="list-group-item">
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <Label class = "bundle-title" [text]="item.Title"></Label>
                    <Label class = "bundle-code" [text]="item.Code"></Label>
                    <Button class="editBundleButton" (tap)="editBundle(item)" text="&#9998;"></Button>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>

    </ListView>
```

> ---

```
public load(args) {
        console.log('load was called');
        this._bdUserService.me().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.bdUser = data.data[0];
                this.bdUserBundles = this.bdUser.Briefs;
                this.htmlUsersToken = data.data[0].Email;
            },
            err => console.log(err)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you try reproducing your issue with nativescript playground?

Comment: Sounds like `_bdUserService.me().subscribe(...)` calls the callbacks outside of Angulars zone. Try `_bdUserService.me().subscribe(() => zone.run(...))`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer and manoj thanks for the responce, i'll have a look into these

Comment: If running it with `zone.run()` fixes it, you should check if there is a way to make the `bdUserService.me()` code run in Angulars zone automatically (without `zone.run()`). Perhaps you just need to initialize the code inside Angular instead of outside (might be something else like using Google maps or GeoLocation API code) that doesn't run outside Angulars zone without special intervention.

Comment: Imported and injected. There should be dozens of examples here on SO, this is why I didn't bother to elaborate. https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone